# Can I create rule to filter all mails to spam except xyz@company.com in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, email-filter, mail-rule

In Outlook I want to create a rule that filters or forwards all emails except the one from my organisation domain (eg.
***@company.com). Any rule which can block or move to spam others apart from company domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to set up the spam filter:

Step 1: Click “Junk” on the ribbon and select “Junk E-mail Options”.

Step 2: Set the spam filter to “Safe Lists Only”

[image]

Step 3: To add an entry to Safe senders and recipients, enter the email address or domain that you want to mark as safe. For example, to mark all email from addresses that end in contoso.com as safe, enter contoso.com in the text box.

[image]

Hope that may help you!

Comment: If you think my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer to help other people.